CORS issue when deploying to server
I am developing a microservice java based project where an API forwards the front-end requests to the correct microservice. I have everything set up on docker and if I deploy it locally using docker my front end is able to do connect with backend and the app works as expected. However, when deploying to a server we can connect to the front end app however, when trying to authenticate the user(first step that connects to backend) the call is failing due to a CORS issue.
Options
Requests
I can see its on the OPTIONS call but in my configuration I have allowed all requests in order to understand why it was happening but even with allow all origins I am still getting error.
Here is my updated config that is still not working:
CorsFilter:
@Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(false);
        config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList(
                "GET",
                "POST",
                "DELETE",
                "PUT",
                "PATCH",
                "OPTIONS"
        ));
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);

    }

I even added an explicit permission for options in order for it to be allowed but i still see the error:
SecurityFilterChain:
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors(withDefaults())
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(req -> req.requestMatchers(
                        "/auth/**",
                        "/v2/api-docs",
                        "/v3/api-docs",
                        "/v3/api-docs/**",
                        "/swagger-resources",
                        "/swagger-resources/**",
                        "/configuration/ui",
                        "/configuration/security",
                        "/swagger-ui/**",
                        "/webjars/**",
                        "/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated())
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

How should I proceed to solve this or to troubleshoot?
Thanks in advance.
